# Initialize $scope.model childs to "" or null

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, web

I'm doing this form and I'm sending the info through a $http request like this with angular

```
$http({
      method:"POST",
      url: "controllers/servicerequest.php", 
      data:
          {  
              servicerequest: $scope.formData 

          },
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

  }).success(function(response, status, headers, config){
      console.log(response);
      if(response.success){
          $window.open('reports/bol.php?bol='+response.id);
          bootbox.alert('Service Request '+response.id+' has been processed.');
      }
      else{
          bootbox.alert('Error message:' + response.message);
      }   
  });
```

as you can see I'm sending all the data in the $scope.formData, the binding of the info works of this 2 ways

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control shipper" ng-model="formData.shipperdescripcion" name="shipper" id="shipper" ui-autocomplete="shipper">
    <span class="help-block">
        {{formData.shipperlocation}}
    </span>
</div>

select: function(event, ui){
      $scope.formData.trailerid = ui.item.id;
      $scope.formData.trailerclave = ui.item.clave;
      $scope.formData.trailerdueno = ui.item.propietario;
      $scope.formData.trailer = ui.item.desc; 
    },
```

The thing is that I need to initialize all of the form data childs to "" when the controller loads otherwhise my the $scope.formData will be looking like this when I send the request

```
{}
```

for example, when I type something in the input the json changes from that, to this

```
{
"shipperdescripcion": "BUENAVENTURA AUTOPARTES S.A. DE C.V.",
}
```

but what I need is that before anything the controller loads the json of this way right from the start like this

```
{
 "shipperdescripcion": "",
}
```

Comment: Please consider rewriting your question to be more coherent and to have more details about your code and the API. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I'm sorry, let me fix this right now

Answer (score 0):

In your controller code, you can initialize the object, like the following:

```
$scope.model = {
  shipperdescription: '', /* changing the spelling here to be correct */
  id: '',
  shipper: '',
  shipperlocation: ''
```

}

A few thoughts: please consider using camelCase if possible to make your code more readable.